# Using a slug instead of an id

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to load an ember-data User model from a route than can accept either a username or an id.

I modified the RESTAdapter find method to pass the id from the JSON response to `didFindRecord`, but nothing gets passed to my view. It seems like the Ember is still trying to use the username as the id of the model.

My router looks like this:

```
App.Router = Em.Router.extend({
  location: 'history'
, root: Em.Route.extend({
    user: Em.Route.extend({
      route: '/users/:slug'
    , connectOutlets: function(router, context) {
        router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('user', context)
      }

    , serialize: function(router, context) {
        return { slug: context.get('username') || context.get('id') }
      }

    , deserialize: function(router, params) {
        return App.User.find(params.slug)
      }
    })
  })
})
```

And my find method looks like this:

```
var CustomAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  find: function(store, type, id) {
    var root = this.rootForType(type)

    this.ajax(this.buildURL(root, id), 'GET', {
      success: function(json) {
        this.didFindRecord(store, type, json, json[root].id)
      }
    })
  }
})

App.store = DS.Store.create({
  revision: 6
, adapter: CustomAdapter.create({ namespace: 'api' })
})
```

Comment: is that ajax request actually fired? (do you get data back?) it might be a problem with changes propagation

Comment: Try doing this:

    Ember.run(this, function(){
       this.didFindRecord(store, type, json, json[root].id);
    });

Answer (score 0):

you should look at this issue :
https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/551